# Import from public folder into src Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

Tell me please, is it possible to import a js file from the public folder, for example, public / content / content.js, into the src folder?

There is a simple children's game, (select the appropriate word, drag the word) ... etc., created on react. There is an array of data with these words, the file is now located in the src folder, this file must be transferred to the public folder, since the pictures related by meaning to this array are in the public folder (in a specific picture, the words to be selected are drawn). Is it possible to somehow import an array from the public folder? Unfortunately, I did not find anything suitable on the network.

Comment: What have you try so far ?

Comment: did you try yourself? what were your findings?

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: You can give relative path to import that js
import CONTENT from '../../public/content/content.js'
your bundler will resolve that file.
But it will not be dynamic if you change content.js then you have to create new bundle

Comment: Why you don't try to include your business logic with content.js inside your react application ?

Comment: Are you using Create React App to bootstrap your project? If that is the case you can't import directly from the public folder.
Here is the documentation for the public folder using CRA: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/.